# Can i enter tag in a tag with css

Tags: html, css

i need to change a element a, while i'm in element b. Can i manage to do so using only CSS/HTML is my question ?

```
li:active{
    img{
       border:1px solid black;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correct, are you looking for something like `li:active + img{border:1px solid black;}` ?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Hey @Nick thanks for your downvote i just deleted but I was not wrong. Next time read the link before you downvote. You did not even understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be wanting...

```
li:active img {
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

this will style *all* `img` elements within `li:active`. If you only want to style *immediate* descendants of the latter, you'll need:

```
li:active > img {
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

I suggest you read up on Chris Coyier's article "[Child and Sibling Selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)" to learn about more complex CSS. Additionally, there are more complex CSS selectors based on positional relationships, such as `li:active + img` and `li:active ~ img`, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

However, what you suggest is actually possible using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), which is a CSS preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

No, What you can do however is be a little more specific with your selector - try the following:

```
li:active img{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Bon Voyage!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
li:active img{
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a descendant selector: `li:active img {boder:1px solid black;}` or a child selector `li:active > img {boder:1px solid black;}` if the `img` is a direct child of the `li`

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 allows for embeded selectors where there is a condition.  An example of valid nested CSS using CSS3 specifications is :

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    ul {
        float: none;
        max-width: auto;
        width: auto;
    }
    div:first-of-type {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The condition set here is to set those styles nested when the `media` type is `screen` (aka desktop), and is no larger than 800px ( `max-width: 800px` ).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following instead:

```
li:active img{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

The syntax you are referring to is similar to [nested rules](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules) in CSS pre-processors such as [**LESS**](http://lesscss.org/). This syntax is not supported natively by browsers and must instead be compiled into valid CSS syntax.

```
#header {
  color: black;
  .navigation {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

Becomes:

```
#header {
  color: black;
}
#header .navigation {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#header .logo {
  width: 300px;
}
```

**http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules**

Comment: The problem with `less` is it is good while defining variables and thus limiting repetition and making it easier to change, however it is not a natural language that is interpreted directly by browsers just yet as it must be "compiled" to css for runtime.  You are correct in the similarity though.

Comment: @SanuelJackson That's correct. I would never suggest client-side processing, but I see huge benefits to server-side precompiling of pre-processors such as LESS/SASS. `dotless` for example is what we use http://www.dotlesscss.org/

Comment: I haven't dug too deep down the less/sass rabbit hole (time issue), however I do see that the language is most definitely useful.  It does throw a curveball to those working with standard CSS, but if the OP has time, it is definitely worth learning -- myself included.

Answer (score 0):

```
    li:active img{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This is the correct answer, if you want to use 2 classes or whatever in 1 clause you put them at the beginning.
NOTE: to concatenate 2 element you do so with a space.
Hope this helped.